# Bootstrap popover causes weird bug in combination with textAngular editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, safari

I've written a custom tool for [textAngular](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular) where you can upload files which are linked in the editor. I've oriented my code on the original [textAngular insertLink tool](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/master/src/textAngularSetup.js#L586-L599).
When the fileupload button is clicked, a bootstrap popover opens, you can upload a file and you can confirm with a button to get the link inserted or the selection linked.
**The problem:** This works only every second time! The problem occures *not* if I run the code in Firefox (Safari and Chrome don't work, other Browsers are not tested). It also occures *not* if I leave out the popover.
I've tried much, but I couldn't find out what's the problem. It seems to be some issue with the combination of Bootstrap popovers, Chrome/Safari & textAngular. 
Here is a (commented) plunker which shows my problem: **[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/CsmLV8x4rKT8llaWwcBL?p=preview)**

//stackoverflow says, i have to accompany links to plunker by code, so here is the core of my problem. i recommend viewing the code in plunker instead..

```
taRegisterTool('fileupload', {
    tooltiptext: 'Upload a file to link to',
    iconclass: 'fa fa-upload',
    action: function () {

        //get editors fileupload button
        var button = $('[name="fileupload"]');

        //create popover content
        var popoverContent = angular.element('<ta-fileupload-popover></ta-fileupload-popover>');

        // the editor fileupload button scope acts as interface between the popover directive and the editor
        // (i don't really like this - is there a better way to let them communicate?)
        var $buttonScope = button.scope();

        //compile content it to the buttons scope
        $compile(popoverContent)($buttonScope);

        //create bootstrap popover
        button.popover({
            content: popoverContent,
            placement: 'bottom',
            container: 'body',
            viewport: button,
            html: true
        });

        //show it
        button.popover('show');

        //..for reference inside performAction function
        var self = this;

        //taFileuploadPopover calls this after finishing the upload
        $buttonScope.performAction = function () {

            //the path where the uploaded file will be
            var urlLink = $buttonScope.taFileUploadAccessPath;

            //wrap selection like in original textangular insertLink tool
            if (urlLink && urlLink !== '' && urlLink !== 'http://') {

                //destroy popover
                button.popover('destroy');

                //urlLink is always correctly defined..
                console.log(urlLink)

                //TODO ..but the wrapping/link insertion only works every second time!!!!!!
                return self.$editor().wrapSelection('createLink', urlLink, true);
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what caused the error: the editor textarea lost focus when I clicked the upload button. This somehow confused the rangy text selection logic and produced the error. This also explains, why the error didn't occur in Firefox, because the browsers handle the focussing events differently. I added a `ng-mousedown="$event.stopPropagation()"` to the button, now everything works fine in all browsers.